# Schwinger proper time representation of log x

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, gamma-function, quantum-field-theory

Is any identity of the form
$$ \log x = \int_0^\infty \frac{ds}s e^{-sx}$$
valid for some range of $x \in \mathbb C$?

Perhaps it will be true with $0$ replaced by some $\epsilon>0$, and up to finite terms, but I'm still interested to see whether one can prove it, perhaps with some manipulations involving Gamma function.

This question arises in quantum field theory.

Comment: For any real $x>0$ the integral is divergent, because the integrand function asymptotically behaves like $1/s$ near $0$. Can you provide one value $x \in \Bbb{C}$ such that the integral is convergent?

Comment: You may already be aware, but $$\log x = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s} - e^{-sx}}{s}\,ds$$ holds for $\operatorname{Re} x > 0$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html